# Did time begin?

Tags: metaphysics, time

I'm still circling around this quasi belief that ends and beginnings are somehow problematic.

Suppose that physicists or philosophers could show that we cannot know when time begins. Would that mean that we cannot know ever know that time has begun?

I.e. is there anything about tense that means that if knowing something in one tense is metaphysically impossible, then we cannot know it in any tense?

Obviously we can know what it was physically impossible to... Right?

Comment: If time has a beginning, then we know exactly when it began: t=0. ;)

Comment: I might look at `episode` as distinguished by Aristotle.  I agree that beginnings and endings are problematic.  When for example did WW2 begin?